# Does >> leave simbolst in the stream?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-keyword, stringstream

The code I wrote below figures the sum of the digits the given number consists of  until sum > 10. So,the questions is: operator ">>" extracts the information from the stream and makes the stream empty ? If it's ,so why can't I perfom "ss<< sum" after I reset the bit of EOF to 0 ?

```
int sum = 0;
stringstream ss("13245");
char ch;
while (1)
{
    while (ss >> ch)
    {
        sum += ch - '0';
    }
    ss.clear();
    ss << sum; //can't perfom
    if (sum<10 ) break;
             sum=0;


}
cout << sum;
```

Comment: Shall one of your "numbers" be "digits"?

Comment: what would you like to see as output ? 6 (1+5) ?

Comment: for example: 
9999 :
1st iteration: 9+9+9+9 = 36;
2nd iteration: 3+6 = 9;
cout<<9;

Comment: Define "can't perform"? The line `ss << sum;` is compiled and executed with no errors, resulting in `ss` holding the buffer "15245" on the first iteration, with the get pointer at end and the put pointer at the character '2'.

Comment: I meant that **sum** isn't inserted to **ss**.Yes it's compiled,it cause no errors ,but doesn't work. It happenes on the second iteration.

Comment: The sum is inserted. On the first iteration it is 15 (which is inserted in positions 1-2), on the second iteration it is 0 (which is inserted in position 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to reset the stream with each iteration, this will likely do what you seek:

```
int sum = 0;
stringstream ss("13245");

while (1)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = ss.get()) != EOF)
        sum += c - '0';

    ss.clear(); // clear stream state
    ss.str(""); // clear buffer
    ss << sum;  // write new data

    if (sum<10 )
        break;

    sum=0;
}
cout << sum;
```

**Output**

```
6
```

Note: I took liberty to use the `get()` member, as it seemed more appropriate for what you were trying to accomplish. And tested with your `9999` aux sample also produces the expected `9` result. To answer your question, yes, the string buffer is not cleared unless *you* clear it (which we do above with `str("")`).

Comment: Yes, **ss.str("")** works, thanks. So, if the buffer is not clear,unless I cleaned it,can I get the information from the buffer again? (The information,left in the buffer after I'd read it at the firs time)

Comment: @GamovCoder sure. just `seekg` to wherever you want (assuming I understood the question correctly). Why you would want to do so I'm not clear, but I suppose you could. Glad it helped, btw.

Comment: ,thanks, you really helped me :)
I didn't know that I could apply 'seekg()' to the stringstream.Always used it to ifstream or ofstream :)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your problem better solved with integer than with strings? Like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename SomeIntegralT>
SomeIntegralT sum_digits(SomeIntegralT n) {
    do {
        SomeIntegralT sum = 0;
        while( n ) {
            sum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        n = sum;
    } while( n > 9 );
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum_digits(124343525ul) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum_digits(9999) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum_digits(12345) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Until the number is something like: `12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890`, probably so.

Comment: Thanks,I just wanted to find out  how to work with " >> " and stringstream .